# #dotnet #blazor #filesUpload => crash when OnChange occured

Tags: .net-core, razor, blazor

if you paste this code:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
<form @onsubmit="OnSubmit">
    <InputFile accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg" OnChange="@OnHandleMultipleFiles" multiple />
    <br />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Envoyer</button>
</form>

@code {
    private IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile> _selectedFiles;
    private void OnHandleMultipleFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        _selectedFiles = e.GetMultipleFiles();
    }
    private void OnSubmit()
    {
        
    }
}
```

In a a #Blazor WebApp under #dotnet8, you will see that app crash when trying to upload something.

Have you got an idea ?
Please, help me.

Regards,
Mafyou.

I tried with InteractiveMode Auto/Client/Server, same result, the app crash always.

EDIT: it only happens with Brave Browser.

Comment: If you want to look on GitHub issue for aspnet it's here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/53507